# adb: unsupported '*' in ANDROID_LOG_TAGS

Tags: android, adb, platform-tools

Just updated Android SDK Platform-tools to 25.0.1 and now observing such a strange behaviour:

```
$ export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS='libc:*'
$ adb
adb F  4886 21476 logging.cpp:290] unsupported 'libc:*' in ANDROID_LOG_TAGS (libc:*)
Abort trap: 6
$ export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS=''
$ adb
adb F  4899 22053 logging.cpp:290] unsupported '' in ANDROID_LOG_TAGS ()
Abort trap: 6
$ unset ANDROID_LOG_TAGS
$ adb
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
...
```

adb seems to be totally unuseable with ANDROID_LOG_TAGS variable defined, and looks like its value doesn't even matters. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been some logging subsystem changes in Android. As a temporary regression `ANDROID_LOG_TAGS` got parsed locally instead of usual pass-through to the device side. [This had been fixed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/295053/) since then. Wait for the next version.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. For those whom it may concern, older platform-tools can be manually downloaded: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-macosx.zip

Comment: thx for the information. unfortunally the latest version of Suchergebnisse `Minimal ADB` contains adb version 1.0.39 
So the only remaining way is to install the full plattform-tools